# How to make an autofill for input type 1 letter at a time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop

```
var addy = "1234567812345678"

function fillAddy(i) {
    var addyKey = addy.substring(0, (addy.length - (addy.length - i) * -1)) 
    $('*[placeholder$="number"]').val(addyKey);
}

for (i = 1; i < addy.length; i++) {
    setTimeout(fillAddy(i), 2000);
}
```

I'm trying to make it so when it fills in addy in the input "[placeholder$="number"]" that it fills it one letter at a time with a 2 second delay each time it adds a letter/number, for some reason it fills it all in at once.

Comment: By the time the first timeout is reached, the loop has long since finished and i === addy.length.

Comment: How should I fix this?

Comment: Just pass the variable to the function: `function fillAddy(i)` and `fillAddy(i)`.

Comment: changed it above^, still doesnt work :/

Comment: What does happen now? All the calls should get separate values now, but they will all run immediately one right after the other, since the timeouts were all started at virtually the same time.

Comment: Same thing as before, would fill it all in at once.

Comment: You would have to not start the next timeout until the previous one ran, such as by starting it within the function.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by using CSS animations:

```
@keyframes animated-text{
  from {width: 0;}
  to {width: 472px;}
}
```

View running [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0p8huq39/). Update the width as per your requirements.

Comment: I'm trying to do it specifically via Javascript since it's something I'm putting in console.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to draw the letters one by one, setTimeout() won't work for loops. Instead you'll need to write recursive(self invoking) function.

Please, take a look at the example, hope this works for you.

```
<div class="div"></div>


var $textOldContainer = $('.div');
var textNew = 'New text';
var textOld = 'old text';
var textOldLength = textOld.length;
var textOldCnt = textOldLength;
var secondTime = false;

function loopChar() {
  if( !secondTime ) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      if( textOldCnt <= textOldLength && textOldCnt >= 0 ) {
        loopChar();
        textOldCnt --;

        $textOldContainer.text( textOld.substring(0, textOldCnt - 1) );
      }

      if( textOldCnt == 0 ) {
        secondTime = true;
      }
    }, 10);
  } else {
    setTimeout(function() {
      if( textOldCnt <= textNew.length ) {
        loopChar();
        textOldCnt++;

        $textOldContainer.text( textNew.substring(0, textOldCnt - 1) );
      }
    }, 50);
  }
}

loopChar();
```

Here is the demo [Demo](https://codepen.io/phpguest/pen/LYpWPrP?editors=1010)